# Why does the modulo operator produces result of the same sign for cases when the operators have the same as well as different signs

Tags: java, javac

```
-10 %  4 = -2  
-10 % -4 = -2
```

Why what the reason?? Same value for different times.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about modular arithmetic (mathematics), not programming.

Comment: See the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3).

Answer (score 1):

It's calculated exactly like the mod of a positive number. In arithmetic modulo c, we seek to express any `x` as `qc + r`, where r must be a non-negative integer.

For example,

Take `−100 % 8 = 4`. This is because `8 ⋅ −13 = −104`. The remainder is `4`.